# Ajuda com relacionamentos no laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou gostando muito de utilizar o laravel 5.4 e estou com algumas duvidas sobre os relacionamentos e qual a melhor forma de utilizar

tenho as tabelas

```
evento
 -id
 -nome
categorias_evento
 -id
 -id_evento
 -nome
lotes_evento
 -id
 -id_categorias_evento
 -valor
itens_evento
 -id
 -id_categorias_evento
 -item
```

Quero entender para poder salvar e acessar as coisas nelas de forma mais dinâmica possível

no model CategoriaEvento eu tenho que criar uma função belongtomany?
e nas outras como fica?

quero gravar tudo dinamicamente e recuperar tudo para popular o formulario (que e todo junto)
qual a melhor forma?

os relacionamentos sao
um evento pode ter varias categorias
uma categoria pode ter varios lotes e varios itens

Comment: A sua pergunta tem duas perguntas uma é como relacionar isso tudo, e a outra é como utilizar isso com as `Views`, seria mais fácil você colocar duas perguntas uma relacionada com a outra, porque os relacionamentos é uma coisa e depois como usar tudo junto seria outro ponto. Para fazer os relacionamentos por exemplo eu precisaria saber os relacionamentos de cada item, isso não está descrito claramente tem como você explicar cada relacionamento?

Comment: fiz a edição para mostrar os relacionamentos, nas views não seria uma consequencia dos relacionamentos? @VirgilioNovic

Comment: na View existe várias formas de implementar isso varia de acordo com cada programador ou estudo de caso ... entendeu... ?

Comment: eu ja ate vi alguns, oq eu pensei que seria colocar um value passando o valor em cada input, tem alguma forma melhor?

Comment: Olha é o que eu disse, vamos resolver o seu problemas por partes, primeiro poderia ser os relacionamentos ???

Comment: Lógico, eu tenho um pouco de dificuldade de entender o hasOne x belongTo e em qual model eu coloco, se no evento ou nos outros

Comment: eu fiz os relacionamentos dê uma olhada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Os relacionamentos são um evento pode ter varias categorias uma categoria pode ter vários lotes e vários itens*

**Evento**

- O relacionamento de Evento para Categorias é **1** para **muitos** [link explicando](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

---

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Evento extends Model
{
    //Nome da tabela.
    protected $table = 'eventos';

    //Primary Key da Tabela.
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    //Item em um Array que são utilizados 
    //para preenchimento da informação.
    protected $fillable   = ['nome'];

    //Deseja trabalhar ou não com campos created_at 
    //e updated_at do tipo timestamp nessa tabela.
    public  $timestamps   = false;

    //Relacionamento 1 para muitos
    public function categorias()
    {
        //     $this->hasMany(relação, chave estrangeira da relação, primary key local);
        return $this->hasMany('App\Categorias', 'id_evento', 'id');
    }

}
```

***Categorias***

- O relacionamento inverso de Categorias para Eventos [link explicando](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).
- O relacionamento de Categorias para Lotes é **1** para **muitos** [link explicando](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
- O relacionamento de Categorias para Itens é **1** para **muitos** [link explicando](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

---

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categorias extends Model
{
    //Nome da tabela.
    protected $table = 'categorias_evento';

    //Primary Key da Tabela.
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    //Item em um Array que são utilizados
    //para preenchimento da informação.
    protected $fillable   = ['id_evento','nome'];

    //Deseja trabalhar ou não com campos created_at
    //e updated_at do tipo timestamp nessa tabela.
    public  $timestamps   = false;

    //Relacionamento
    public function evento()
    {
        //$this->belongsTo(relação, chave estrangeira local, primary key da relação);
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Evento', 'id_evento', 'id');
    }

    //Relacionamento 1 para muitos
    public function lotes()
    {
        //$this->hasMany(relação, chave estrangeira da relação, primary key local);
        return $this->hasMany('App\Lotes', 'id_categorias_evento', 'id');
    }

    //Relacionamento 1 para muitos
    public function itens()
    {
        //$this->hasMany(relação, chave estrangeira da relação, primary key local);
        return $this->hasMany('App\Itens', 'id_categorias_evento', 'id');
    }
}
```

***Lotes***

- O relacionamento inverso de Lotes para Categorias [link explicando](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

---

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Lotes extends Model
{
    //Nome da tabela.
    protected $table = 'lotes_evento';

    //Primary Key da Tabela.
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    //Item em um Array que são utilizados 
    //para preenchimento da informação.
    protected $fillable   = ['id_categorias_evento','valor'];

    //Deseja trabalhar ou não com campos created_at 
    //e updated_at do tipo timestamp nessa tabela.
    public  $timestamps   = false;

    //Relacionamento
    public function categorias()
    {
        //$this->belongsTo(relação, chave estrangeira local, primary key da relação);
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categorias', 'id_categorias_evento', 'id');
    }

}
```

***Itens***

- O relacionamento inverso de Lotes para Categorias [link explicando](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

---

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Itens extends Model
{
    //Nome da tabela.
    protected $table = 'itens_evento';

    //Primary Key da Tabela.
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    //Item em um Array que são utilizados 
    //para preenchimento da informação.
    protected $fillable   = ['id_categorias_evento','item'];

    //Deseja trabalhar ou não com campos created_at 
    //e updated_at do tipo timestamp nessa tabela.
    public  $timestamps   = false;

    //Relacionamento
    public function categorias()
    {
        //$this->belongsTo(relação, chave estrangeira local, primary key da relação);
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categorias', 'id_categorias_evento', 'id');
    }

}
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Eloquent - Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)
- [Eloquent - Relationships: one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
- [Eloquent - Relationships: one-to-many (Inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Comment: Muitissimo obrigado, mais que uma resposta uma aula