# Resultado nome do campo ao inves do id no Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um relacionamento no `Laravel` mas quando eu faço uma consulta vem o `id` e não o nome do campo.

Model `Evento`

```
    public function tipo_evento() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\TipoEvento','id','tipo_evento');
}
```

Model `TipoEvento`

```
    public function evento() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Evento');
}
```

No `controller`

`$eventos = Evento::with('tipo_evento')->get();`

As tabelas são

```
Eventos
  -id (1)
  -nome_evento(blabla)
  -tipo_evento(1)
```

---

```
Tipo Evento
  -id(1)
  -nome(festa)
```

quero ao usar `$eventos = Evento::with('tipo_evento')->get();` vir `tipo_evento` **festa** não **1** como ta vindo?

Comment: O relacionamento ta errado

Comment: eu imaginei que seria isso mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os relacionamentos de ***[1 para muitos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)*** nesses dois `Models` e a *nomenclatura* para funcionar seria:

Classe `Evento`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Evento extends Model
{
    protected $table = "eventos";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = ['nome_evento', 'tipo_evento'];

    public function tipoEvento()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TipoEvento','tipo_evento','id');
    }
}
```

---

Classe `TipoEvento`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TipoEvento extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tipoeventos";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = ['nome'];

    public function eventos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Evento','tipo_evento','id');
    }
}
```

***Como utilizar?***

```
foreach (Evento::with('tipoevento')->get() as $evento)
{
    echo $evento->tipoevento->nome;
}
```

ou fazendo `inner join` também:

```
$eventos = Evento::join('tipoeventos', 'tipoeventos.id','=','eventos.id')
            ->select('tipoeventos.nome', 'eventos.id', 'eventos.nome_evento')
            ->get();

foreach ($eventos as $evento)
{
    echo $evento->nome;
}
```

***Observação:*** verifique as alterações, o jeito de escrever os métodos e observe também as relações ...

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Eloquent - Relationships (one-to-many)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
- [Eloquent - Relationships (One To Many (Inverse))](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)
- [Eloquent - Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#joins)
- [Ajuda com relacionamentos no laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/211603/54880)
- [Problemas com relacionamento um para muitos laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152108/54880)

Comment: quando eu uso hasOne?

Comment: @GuilhermeFreire quando a relação tiver somente somente 1 item diferente da coleção que pode ter vários itens, nesse caso eu sugeri a melhor proposta que seria 1 para N, mas, por exemplo [nesse link explica](http://artesaos.github.io/howto/eloquent-one-to-one/) bem melhor, particularmente é bem pouco usado, mas, é uma opção que existe em certos casos.

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
foreach ( Evento::with('tipo_evento')->get() as $evento )
{
    echo $evento->tipo_evento->nome;
}
```

Comment: onde que eu colocaria isso, no model?

Comment: Sim, desculpas vou editar pra ficar mais claro.

Comment: se eu coloco o withPivot da erro e nem reconhece o relacionamento coloquei >withPivot('nome','tipo_evento')

Comment: Qual versão você está utilizando?

Comment: estou usando a ultima versao laravel 5.4

Comment: Desfaz o que você tinha feito anteriormente e tenta fazer o que eu coloquei agora na resposta.

Comment: agora deu erro no $evento->tipo_evento->nome; falando q tipo_evento nao e um objeto (coloquei no controller)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60325/discussion-between-kayo-bruno-and-guilherme-freire).